# Dynamically add element and class using React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a small app that takes user-inputted text and highlights the consonants and vowels in each word inputted by the user.

I am unsure how to add the new `span` element that gets created via a function call into the actual DOM (I am new to react).

Here is where I have gotten to:

```
import React from "react";

import "./AnalysisArea.css";

const AnalysisArea = (props) => {
  const graphemes = props.text.split("");
  console.log(graphemes);
  const analyseText = () => {
    const getClass = (character) => {
      if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(character)) {
        return "vowel-class";
      } else {
        return "consonant-class";
      }
    };

    //the span
    return graphemes.map((character, i) => {
      return(
      <span class={getClass(character)}>
        {(i === 0 ? "" : ",") + character}
      </span>
      )
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="analysisframe">
      <button onClick={analyseText}>Analyse</button>
      <div>
        <p>{props.text}</p> //this is where the span should go 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AnalysisArea;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very common to use `Array.prototype.map()` to render React elements. I would suggest something like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./AnalysisArea.css";

const getClass = (character) => {
  if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(character)) {
    return "vowel-class";
  } else {
    return "consonant-class";
  }
};

const AnalysisArea = (props) => {
  const [showAnalysis, setShowAnalysis] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="analysisframe">
      <button onClick={() => setShowAnalysis(true)}>Analyse</button>
      <div>
        <p>
          {showAnalysis &&
            props.text.split("").map((character, i) => {
              return (
                <span key={i} class={getClass(character)}>
                  {(i === 0 ? "" : ",") + character}
                </span>
              );
            })}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AnalysisArea;
```